# Script to update json file

Tags: python, json

Python script which takes two inputs and then deletes some items

```json
{
    "a": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ],
    "b": [
      "four",
      "five",
      "six"
    ],
    "c": [
      "seven",
      "eight",
      "nine",
      "ten"
    ]
}
```

Python script:

```
import json
import sys

alphaname=sys.argv[1]
numname=sys.argv[2]

with open('test.json', 'r+') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  del data[alphaname][numname]
```

When I run the script `python purest.py a three`,
it should remove `three` from `a` and update the json file.

Here is the error:

```
del data[alphaname][numname]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: it gives me del data[alphaname][numname]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: The values in your dictionary are lists. You can't access list values by a name. You need to access them by their indices. Something like this `del data['a'][1]`.

Comment: what are the arguments that you passed

Comment: Hi @martineau I have provided a solution. That should work. Please do take a look. Since it had code I couldn't post it in the comments.

Comment: @SachinPC: It may work (now that you've fixed the `TypeError`), but things could be done a little more efficiently…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
import json
import sys

alphaname = sys.argv[1]
numname = sys.argv[2]
filename = 'update_me.json'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data[alphaname].remove(numname)

# Update file.
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numname` is a string when it is received from as a parameter when you run the program using `python purest.py a three`.

The `data[alphaname]` gives you an array which is the value for the key `a`

=> Your output for `data[alphaname]` will be ["one","two","three"]

you may add the following piece of code(a very basic way of solving):

```
import json
temp_list = []
for i in range(len(data[alphaname])):
   if data[alphaname][i] != numname:
       temp_list.append(data[alphaname][i])
data.update({alphaname:temp_list})

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Do let me know if this works out for you.
All the best.

Comment: if data[alphaname][i] != numname:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode .

Comment: Sorry, abt that, I missed that out. I have updated the answer @user17970.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.